# Is a sharepoint installation required to edit a sharepoint profile image using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sharepoint

Is a sharepoint installation required to edit a sharepoint profile image using c# or vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly. Why do you think it requires such thing?

The installation process doesn't required any c# or vb.net custom code.

Comment: Sorry that was not I meant. I wanted to write a code in c# using VS 2010 to edit profile image of sharepoint version 2010 (deployed in some server which is live). Can I write console application for editing profile image of live sharepoint without any sharepoint framework installed in my local system using just c# language.

Comment: If you want to follow the recommended way you should install SharePoint server on your development machine. If you really don't want to do it you can register Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll in GAC and try to write some CSOM application. But I recommend to install SP Server on dev machine.